# Need reference materials for BLE hcitool?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, firmware

I am preparing commands for FCC certification.  I got some hcitool commands from the BLE chip vendor, but not sure what it means.  What is ocf, ogf?  What is OCF=0x0051 or OGF=0x3F? Looked around the web and found nothing.  Can anyone please provide me some reference materials?

Answer (score 1):

OCF and OGF are two parts of commands sent to the MCU.

- OCF: Opcode Command Field
- OGF: Opcode Group Field

The third part of a command is the command parameters.

(A little Googling turns this up without much effort.)